# Print latest Date where Status= 'IN_PROGRESS' in XSLT code

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is the XML-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <wd:Get_Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshots_Response
            xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            wd:version="v35.0">
            <wd:Response_Data>
                <wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data>
                    <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                    <wd:Effective_Date>2013-08-17</wd:Effective_Date>
                    <wd:Program_of_Study_Record_Status_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Student_Program_of_Study_Record_Status_ID">MATRICULATED</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Program_of_Study_Record_Status_Reference>
                </wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data>
                
                <wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data>
                    <wd:Order>c</wd:Order>
                    <wd:Effective_Date>2013-06-17</wd:Effective_Date>
                    <wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Subedit_Data>
                        <wd:Program_of_Study_Record_Status_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Student_Program_of_Study_Record_Status_ID">IN_PROGRESS</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Program_of_Study_Record_Status_Reference>
                    </wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Subedit_Data>
                </wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data>
                
                <wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data>
                    <wd:Order>b</wd:Order>
                    <wd:Effective_Date>2019-09-19</wd:Effective_Date>
                    <wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Subedit_Data>
                        <wd:Program_of_Study_Record_Status_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Student_Program_of_Study_Record_Status_ID">IN_PROGRESS</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Program_of_Study_Record_Status_Reference>
                    </wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Subedit_Data>
                </wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data>
                
                <wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data>
                    <wd:Order>d</wd:Order>
                    <wd:Effective_Date>2020-09-14</wd:Effective_Date>
                    <wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Subedit_Data>
                        <wd:Program_of_Study_Record_Status_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Student_Program_of_Study_Record_Status_ID">COMPLETE</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Program_of_Study_Record_Status_Reference>
                    </wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Subedit_Data>
                </wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data>
            </wd:Response_Data>
        </wd:Get_Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshots_Response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Below is my XSLT to print Latest Effective Date where Status is 'IN_PROGRESS', But this code is not giving me any data-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    >
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <File>
            <xsl:variable name="MatriculationDate">
                <xsl:for-each select="env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshots_Response/wd:Response_Data/
                    wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data">
                    <xsl:sort select="wd:Effective_Date" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when
                            test="contains(wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data/wd:Program_of_Study_Record_Status_Reference/
                            wd:ID [@wd:type = 'Student_Program_of_Study_Record_Status_ID'], 'IN_PROGRESS')">
                            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_Date"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <data>
                <m>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$MatriculationDate" />
                </m>
                
            </data>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to print the latest Effective date (in this xml '2019-09-19'), where Status is 'IN_PROGRESS'.
Can anyone please help me with this XSLT code.

Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> print Latest Effective Date where Status is 'IN_PROGRESS'

This could look like follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
  xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="wd env"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <File>
      <data>
        <m>
          <xsl:for-each select="//wd:Program_of_Study_Assignment_Snapshot_Data[
            .//wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Student_Program_of_Study_Record_Status_ID'] = 'IN_PROGRESS'
          ]">
            <xsl:sort select="wd:Effective_Date" order="descending" />
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_Date" />
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </m>
      </data>
    </File>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<File>
  <data>
    <m>2019-09-19</m>
  </data>
</File>
```